# Search all properties that are string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is there anyway to do change the "Where", in which it will automatic check all properties that contain a string instead of adding each property name manually?

```
 items.Where(m => m.Property1.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
                                || m.Property2.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
                                || m.Property3.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
                                || m.Property4?.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
                                || m.Property5?.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
                                || m.Property6.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
                                || m.Property7?.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
                                ));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use *reflection*?

Comment: `m.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => p.ReturnType == typeof(string))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write a code using reflection...

```
public bool MyContains(object instance, string word)
{
        return instance.GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                .Select(x => (string)x.GetValue(instance, null))
                .Where(x => x != null)
                .Any(x => x.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
}
```

Then your code would be

```
items.Where(m=>MyContains(m,word));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Based on L.B answer:** I accepted his answer

> I broke it down into two functions because there is no need to get
>   the string properties for each instances in the where.

```
public static class ObjectUtils
{
    public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesByType<TEntity>(TEntity entity, Type type)
        {
            return entity.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == type); 
        }

    public static bool CheckAllStringProperties<TEntity>(TEntity instance, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> stringProperties, string word)
        {
            return stringProperties.Select(x => (string)x.GetValue(instance, null))
                .Where(x => x != null)
                .Any(x => x.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
        }
}
```

Then

```
var stringProperties = ObjectUtils.GetPropertiesByType(new Item(), typeof(string)); 

 items.Where(x => ObjectUtils.CheckAllStringProperties(x, stringProperties, word)));
```