# Read model properties where model is passed as an Anonymous object - C#

Tags: c#, model, anonymous-objects

I am working with a method that takes an anonymous object and a string, and then compares the string to the object property names.

In this example the object is a model that contains basic properties and a custom class property:

Model:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AddressClass Address { get; set; }
}

public class AddressClass
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
}
```

The method (the MyClass model is being passed):

```
protected string GetPropertyName(object model, string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyInfo = model.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(pi => pi.Name == propertyName);

        return propertyInfo;
    }
```

This code is working and returning 'Name' where the string is equal to 'Name'. But not working for 'AddressLine1' or 'AddressLine2' properties when the string is equal to those values. Instead it returns Null.

In this example is it possible to reach inside the model object, to compare the string, without specifying that model type in the method?

Thanks

Comment: You mean you gave a MyClass instance to that method and asked for a propertyname in the AddressClass class?

Comment: Hi Ralf - yes correct. I shall edit to make that clear.

Comment: [Was not able to repro](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0AMgJZQCOA3OlrgQEoCmAZgDYMDGwxA9lFWtSQBOABQBxBsAAKYbgAcGYYAE8AcgEMAtgxFQGAd2wBBACYmwDAM6WAwi3XWRASgA02AESnzVyyT1J3Jyd+dHQZeUUVAEkoJm5sCWlZBSU1LR1uACMAKw5gbE1uEwYWNzwcOWTItO0ndABvdGxm7AA3dTBsSojUmLjsAF4CopL8RIAVZQVnMclwlK4rGYAxYjBLYAB5MAARZnUIFmAROWJBgD4u4nwNbUGh7oWahmDQtBbcAHYuqt7Y7n4AF83ohsABZZR2ByWBpNFpwADMtBwtwY2Hq2AA5pIKNhLDjsMD3vCkV4LNYodZjGZyZZ0ViCfjgLiiUTqEjQWSfJSYWhGsTmojkdTvNY/AwkPTscy8QSiR8heURbTxQgpYy5ehAUA=)

Comment: @GuruStron - you passed an instance of AddressClass and not MyClass - OP is looking for a way to search for nested objects

Comment: @RandRandom I understand that =)

Comment: something like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/3wkXgl

Comment: Also what if `MyClass` has two properties of `AddressClass` type? What if it has property of another type which has `AddressLine1` property. Why at all you need reflection here?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299682

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Is the return value of the method the value of that property or do you just want to know if the object has said property?

Your method is returning a PropertyInfo object, but is defined as a string

Comment: Hi Kasper - the method is a little simplified but I am trying to understand if the object has the said property, and if so, return that property name. Thanks

Comment: why aren't you simply calling `GetProperty(propertyName)` and check if this returns null or not?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused what you need this for. Having the name of a property and an unknown model seems rather weird.

In any case, you can just loop through the properties and their properties.
I've done it below using recursion.
If you need the value of the property you need to change a few things.

```
protected string GetPropertyName(object model, string propertyName)
{
    var propInfo = model as PropertyInfo;
    var props = propInfo != null ? propInfo.PropertyType.GetProperties() : model.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        if (prop.Name == propertyName)
            return prop.Name;

        var subProb = GetPropertyName(prop, propertyName);
        if (subProb != null)
            return subProb;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Notice: in my solution (in comments) I have added the check for type (`if (type == typeof(MyClass) && pi.PropertyType == typeof(AddressClass))`) to prevent a stackoverflow if you have this setup: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pexSjd - which isn't an issue here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uPE1i5